# SSL Error : Python Multiprocessing, PostgresSQL and Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, multiprocessing, psycopg2

## How can I call with more than one processes?

Below code is working fine for processes = 1.

Definition:

```
def origin_and_url_from_url(url):
    ori_url = url.strip() 
    cursor = connection.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT url, id FROM origin where url = %s",[ori_url])
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    for a_row in rows:
        with open('TopListwith100CardsWithID.csv','a') as file:
            file.write(str(a_row[1])+ ", ")
            file.write(str(a_row[0]))
            file.write('\n')
```

Call:

```
with open('SEMethodologies/TopListwith100Cards.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    top_list = list(reader)
p = multiprocessing.Pool(1, initializer, ())
logger.info("Pool Started for ids")
results = p.starmap(origin_and_url_from_url, top_list)
print(results)
p.close()
```

But if I call by changing this line `p = multiprocessing.Pool(2, initializer, ())` for two processes, Its shows this error **psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record Mac**

Comment: Every process has to create its own connection.

Comment: Explanation why multiprocessing with same connection object doesn't work - https://virtualandy.wordpress.com/2019/09/04/a-fix-for-operationalerror-psycopg2-operationalerror-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-record-mac/

Answer (score 0):

I had a very pesky bug that sounds similar - my service would restart with this error

```
Corruption detected. Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
Decryption error: TSI_DATA_CORRUPTED
```

Running a Gunicorn service in Google Cloud with a Postgres DB. Ended up debugging a lot of multiprocessing configurations, Postgres settings, etc.

The thing that fixed it for me was freezing the `grpcio` python package at `1.29.0`, based on [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11011#issuecomment-301845722) answer which says that the decryption failure error happens after GRPC v1.3.x.